# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function have_posts() on array

Tags: php, wordpress

I develop in wordpress and I have an error.
I create a template file with this line to display all ads who are Type "Flash"

```
<?php

         $sql = "
    SELECT distinct p.* 
    FROM $wpdb->posts p, ".$wpdb->prefix."p2p pp
    WHERE p.ID = pp.p2p_to
    AND exists (select meta_id from ".$wpdb->prefix."p2pmeta m where m.p2p_id = pp.p2p_id and m.meta_key='type' and m.meta_value like '%flash%')
    AND exists (select meta_value from $wpdb->postmeta g where g.post_id = p.ID and g.meta_key='cp_sys_expire_date' and g.meta_value >= now())
    AND p.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND p.post_type = 'ad_listing'
    ORDER BY p.post_date DESC";

                 $flash_ads = $wpdb->get_results($sql, OBJECT);
                 $result = '';

?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area row">

    <div class="columns">

        <?php get_template_part( 'parts/breadcrumbs', app_template_base() ); ?>

    </div>

    <main id="main" class="site-main small-12 columns" role="main">

            <?php if ( $flash_ads->have_posts() ) : ?> 

            <div class="row entry-wrap small-up-1 medium-up-2 large-up-3">

                <?php while ( $flash_ads->have_posts() ): $flash_ads->the_post();  ?>

                <div class="column">

                <?php get_template_part( 'parts/content-item', APP_POST_TYPE ); ?>

                </div> <!-- .column -->

              <?php endwhile; ?>

            </div> <!-- .row --> 

            <?php cp_do_pagination(); ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <?php appthemes_loop_else( get_post_type() ); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'parts/content-none', get_post_type() ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?> 

        <?php appthemes_after_loop( get_post_type() ); ?>
```

I don't know where are my errors...
Thank's a lot for your help.
Cyberm

Comment: It is saying that `$flash_ads` is not an object but array... var_dump it to see what is in there

Comment: `$flash_ads` is an array, because that is what `$wpdb->get_results` returns. Just check with `count($flash_ads)` instead, if you need to know whether this contains any posts, or is simply empty.

Comment: `$flash_ads->the_post()` will not work either though. If you want to work with these methods, you must call them on a `WP_Query` instance.

Comment: Or, if you want to keep it this way, and loop over an array of post objects, you can call `setup_postdata` first, and then use the normal “the loop” template functions, as in this example: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Examples_3

Answer (score 1):

You don't use WP_Query, but custom SQL query:

```
$flash_ads = $wpdb->get_results($sql, OBJECT);
```

`get_results` returns you an array of rows. But later in your code you do this:

```
<?php if ( $flash_ads->have_posts() ) : ?>
```

So you treat that array as an WP_Query instance... And that's the problem.

So there are two ways to fix this:

### 1. Use WP_Query instead

You can use WP_Query instead of custom SQL query.

```
$flash_ads = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'ad_listing',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    ...
) );
```

And then you can use it as you do in your code.

### 2. Change your loop

Or you can still use your custom SQL query (I wouldn't recommend that), but in such case you have to rebuild your loop.

This:

```
<?php if ( $flash_ads->have_posts() ) : ?>
```

should become this:

```
<?php if ( ! empty($flash_ads) ) : ?>
```

And this:

```
<?php while ( $flash_ads->have_posts() ): $flash_ads->the_post();  ?>
```

Should become this:

```
<?php foreach ( $flash_ads as $row ) : ?>
```

But in such case you can't use template tags to print the values any more, because no global `$post` is set up.